# How to draw a circle on a bitmap without filling it?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am ddrawing a circle on the bitmap and setting this bitmap to ImageView. the circle is drawn correctly but i dont want it to be a filled circle is there any way to make the filled area transparent?
i am using the following code

```
Bitmap bmp = RasterImageConverter.convertToBitmap(_loadedImage, ConvertToImageOptions.NONE.getValue());
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
c = new Canvas(bmp);
myimgview.draw(c);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.RED);
float x=(float) circleX;
float y=(float) circleY;
float Tx=(float) textX;
float Ty=(float)textY;
// c.drawLine(x, y, xend, yend, p);
c.drawCircle(300, 300, 200, p);
c.drawText(myText, Tx, Ty, p);
myimgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inform the paint that you dont' use a fill style, but a stroke style.

[The default is FILL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html)

> The Style specifies if the primitive being drawn is filled, stroked, or both (in the same color). **The default is FILL.**

So your code must be:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html) are explained the differences between the different styles.

> **STROKE**
>   Geometry and text drawn with this style will be stroked, respecting the stroke-related fields on the paint.
>
> **FILL**
>   Geometry and text drawn with this style will be filled, ignoring all stroke-related settings in the paint.
>
> **FILL_AND_STROKE**
>   Geometry and text drawn with this style will be both filled and stroked at the same time, respecting the stroke-related fields on the paint.

Comment: @Android_Learner if you find that an answer is useful you can upvote it and eventually flag it as the right answer with the green flag

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Paint style to stroke:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style)) method on your paint p instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there... you need to set the [style of the Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html) object...

by invoking the method

```
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

The options are:

[image]

## Example:

```
Bitmap bmp = RasterImageConverter.convertToBitmap(_loadedImage, ConvertToImageOptions.NONE.getValue());
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
c = new Canvas(bmp);
myimgview.draw(c);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.RED);
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: you are welcome, dont forget to Vote Up / accept the answer